# QMake still runs mkdir event if the directory exists

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to create a directory and copy files to using QMAKE.

```
DESTDIR_Lang = Debug\Languages
!exists("Debug\Languages"){
    message("false")
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(mkdir $${DESTDIR_Lang} $$escape_expand(\n\t))
}

QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\de.xml Debug\Languages\de.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\en.xml Debug\Languages\en.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\es.xml Debug\Languages\es.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\fr.xml Debug\Languages\fr.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\gb.xml Debug\Languages\gb.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\it.xml Debug\Languages\it.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\ja.xml Debug\Languages\ja.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\ko.xml Debug\Languages\ko.xml &
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy ..\XYZ\Languages\zh.xml Debug\Languages\zh.xml
```

It can successfully create the directory on first run if it doesn't exist. But if I change something in the code, it shows this error on build:

[image]

It seems like it did not recognize the **!exists** and still tried to create the directory or are there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: try `exists($$DESTDIR_Lang)`

Comment: You must use slash instead of backslash even under Windows.